# Android : Reading a file from my app by just clicking on it

Tags: android, file, onclick

I have this issue:
I want to create an Android App that will read a certain file type (as is the case in PDF or MP3 players), the problem is that I dont know how to read a file with my application just by clicking on it
if anyone knows how to do this in android please help

i well be grateful for your help, thank you for your time and consideration and so sorry for my  english

Comment: The user clicks on a file? Where? Where does the user see files? Which file type exactly? What is in it that you want to read?

Comment: In general you should open a FileInputStream for the file and then read from the stream.

Comment: the files will be on  a directory on the local disk of the system , what i want is the action of clicking that file should run my application and getting the data from this file. just like a mediaplayer or a book reader work

Comment: `what i want is the action of clicking that file` Again: What is the user doing that he sees files where he can click upon?

Comment: the file will be stored in the disc

Comment: in the same manner when you click your MP3 files to listen music

Comment: I do not know where you are talking about. Of course the files are stored on disk. But which spp does the user use to see these files so he can click on them? So tell exactly what the user does to listen music and then sees mp3 files.

Comment: the user can see these file by using Android OS

Comment: An aandroid device of course. Please tell exactly the steps you have in mind for the user to be able to choose mp3 files. If i boot my Android device i see no mp3 files. So what should i do exactly to see them?

Comment: step 0 - boot your android device ------->
step 2 - got to ur SD Card or local disc------->
step 3 - Assuming that you have a mp3 file in one of these discs, clik on it..........
that will automatically trigger a default app that will read this mp3 file.

my issue is how to do somthing like that

Comment: I do not know how to go to sd card. Which app should i use for that?

Comment: `that will automatically trigger a default app`. Dont think so. I think the user will see a list of apps that can play a mp3 file. The user chooses an app then.

Comment: yes we agree, but how to bring up my own app in this list ??

Comment: You did not tell that the user stsrted a file explorer to see the files. And not in that list of course as you have a special file type..  A different list. Define an <intent-filter> for your special file type for the activity in your app that you want to start if the user clicks your file. Do this in the manifest file. Google for intent filter.

Comment: thank you very much, and so sorry for derangement  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String outputFile = "my_patch.mp3";

button_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

//this content
MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
           m.setDataSource(outputFile);
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
           m.prepare();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        m.start();

}
});
```

and open file pdf, you make library pdf-view to android studio https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

good luck..

Comment: thanks for tour feedback,   I don't want to specify the file name in the code, Iwant  click on a file with a given extension (i.e .mp3) and my application should run to read this file. (like an AudioPlayer or a pdfPlayer)